# Windows Mobile Wifi Networking After Wake Up From Sleep

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

I am developing a windows mobile application in c# that makes calls to a web service on a separate thread to the UI.  This thread runs every few minutes triggered by a timer.

My problem is that if the hand held device goes to sleep, when it wakes up the OS seems to unload the networking and then restart the networking a second or so later.

The result of this more often than not is my application crashes.

Has anyone experienced a similar scenario?

Has anybody had to code around this problem?

Any help or comments would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should add some exception handling on your thread.

Surround your networking code with a try catch block and retry the operation later:

```
try {
    // your code 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // add some logging
}
```

Comment: I do have some exception handling in place as a kind of catch all to write out to a log file.  Your suggestion to catch things at a lower level and retry is worth exploring.  Thanks

Comment: When your app crashes you definitly have some unhandled exception throwing.

Comment: I have put some exception handling and logging around all my web service calls.  All seems to be working fine.  Thanks for you guidance.